# Snapping one orientation to another?

Tags: modeling, snapping, transform-orientation

I want to be able to move a face, edge or vertex along an orientation and snap it to the intersecting point of another orientation. Is this possible in blender currently? 
[image]

Comment: The easiest way could be to move edge along normals of the top plane so that they intersect (e.g. with it selected press G twice and then Alt), confirm that and intersect geometry with Ctrl+F> Knife. This won't snap rather than create new vertices at intersection

Answer (score 0):

I have two ideas.

first one summarized in this image, using local transformations and face snap. moving using 3d cursor transformation or moving first the center point to edge.

[image: idea]

the second is use some script like this:

```
import bpy

from mathutils import Vector, geometry
from math import sqrt

print("#"*20)

#"object names"
n1 ="Plane"
n2 = "a" #this is the object to move

#data object 1
object = bpy.data.objects[n1]
object.select = True

bpy.context.scene.objects.active = object

v11,v12,v13, v14 = [(object.matrix_world*v.co) for v in object.data.vertices]

ob1_normal = geometry.normal(v11,v12,v13)

print(v11,v12,v13,ob1_normal)

bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')

#data object 2

object = bpy.data.objects[n2]
object.select = True

bpy.context.scene.objects.active = object

v21,v22,v23, v24 = [(object.matrix_world*v.co) for v in object.data.vertices]

ob2_normal = geometry.normal(v21,v22,v23)

#print(v21,v22,v23,ob2_normal)

##############################intersection point


int = geometry.intersect_plane_plane(v11, ob1_normal, v22, ob2_normal)
#bpy.context.scene.cursor_location = int[0]

#print("new",int)
distance = (v22 - int[0]).length  #distance vertice and intersection point
#print("distance ", distance)

### translate the object

bpy.ops.transform.translate(value=(distance, 0, 0), constraint_axis=(True, False, False), constraint_orientation='LOCAL', mirror=False, proportional='DISABLED', proportional_edit_falloff='SMOOTH', proportional_size=1, release_confirm=True, use_accurate=False)
```

[image: script example]